# How can i Cherry pick a commit of another branch using TortoiseGit without committing?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I can cherry pick a commit using bash

```
git cherry-pick -n <HASH>
```

But is there any way to do that by using TortoiseGit?

Comment: There is issue about it at https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/-/issues/3268. I hope the team implements this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Checkout the branch on which you want to cherry pick the commit it. Then

- open the Log Dialog,
- scroll to the commit (maybe you have to select "all branches" in the lower left or use the top-left blue branch name to select the source branch and filter the list for the commit hash),
- open the context menu on the commit and
- select "Cherry pick this commit...".

Now you basically have two options as the `-n` option is not directly available in TortoiseGit.

1) Change the cherry-pick type from "Pick" to "Edit", start the cherry-pick and then, check the "Edit commit" checkbox, keep the commit dialog open, do your changes and then commit and finish the cherry-pick.

2) Finish the cherry pick and then

- go to your HEAD commit,
- select the parent commit of the just cherry picket commit,
- and choose "Reset" on the context menu and
- select mixed.

cf. https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-cherrypick.html

Comment: thank you very much for your quick response. That's really a nice trick specially reset after commit. :)

Answer (score 5):

Suppose you want to cherry-pick Commit X from `dev` to `master`.

1. Right click in the repository and select TortoiseGit -> Switch/Checkout -> select `master` and press OK.
2. Right click in the repository and select TortoiseGit -> Browse references -> Right click on `dev` -> Show log.
3. Right click on the commit you want to cherryp-pick and select Cherry Pick this commit -> Continue.
4. Since the cherry-pick menu doesn't support the option `-n`, we can do a mixed reset back to the previous commit to simulate `-n`. TortoiseGit -> Browse references -> Right click on `master` -> Show log -> Right click on the previous commit -> Reset "master" to this... -> Press OK.